# What does $\dot x$ mean as an operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, velocity, differentiation, notation

I've been looking at a paper titled "Feynman's proof of the Maxwell Equations" by Freeman Dyson (American Journal of Physics 58, 209 (1990); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.16188) and I'm confused by his notation, as in these equations (original equation numbering):
$$m\ddot x_j = F_j(x,\dot x,t) \tag{1}$$
$$[x_j, x_k] = 0 \tag{2} $$
$$m[x_j,\dot x_k] = i\hbar \delta_{jk} \tag{3} $$
$$[x_j, F_k] + m[\dot x_j, \dot x_k] = 0 \tag{9}$$

Everything inside a commutator has to be an operator to make sense.  I understand $x_j$ as the operator meaning "multiply by the scalar $x_j$", but what do $\dot x_j$ and $\ddot x_j$ mean as operators?  Is (2) trivially true, since multiplication by a scalar is commutative?

Comment: In the Heisenberg picture, the notion of the time-derivative of an operator is straightforward. Do you have reason to believe this is something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\dot{\hat{x}}$ means the same thing it does in Newtonian mechanics.

$$\dot{\hat{x}} = \frac{d\hat{x}}{dt}.$$

The trick is this is happening in the Heisenberg picture, not the Schrodinger picture that textbooks typically start with. There, you set an initial quantum state and then let the *operators* evolve with time. Hence that $\hat{x}$ acts on a positional wave function by multiplying by the position is only usually so at time zero.

The commutator relation,

$$m [\hat{x}, \dot{\hat{x}}] = i\hbar$$

establishes what $\dot{\hat{x}}$ is at time zero. Namely $-\frac{i\hbar}{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ when working on a positional wave function and where $\hat{x}$ is as you described (multiplying by position).

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was missing.  So (2) is only trivially true at $t=0$ and becomes a non-trivial condition at other times?

Comment: It's true at all times (whether or not you want to call it "trivial" is up to you) because the internal $e^{-iHt}e^{iHt}$ factors in each product in the commutator are equal to one so that: $[x_i(t), x_j(t)] = e^{-iHt}[x_i,x_j]e^{iHt} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

1. In the [Heisenberg picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) operators evolve in time, and
   dot denotes a time derivative
   $$ \dot{\hat{x}}^j~:=~\frac{d\hat{x}^j}{dt}, \qquad 
   \ddot{\hat{x}}^j~:=~\frac{d^2\hat{x}^j}{dt^2},\tag{A}$$
   cf. the answer by The_Sympathizer.
2. Normally in the Heisenberg picture we assume a Hamiltonian time evolution, so that we can effectively define the velocity operator via Heisenberg's EOM
   $$ \dot{\hat{x}}^j~=~\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{x}^j,\hat{H}],\tag{B}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430118/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. However, it is an important point in Feynman's proof that he does *not* assume eq. (B) *nor* the standard [CCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation), cf. section II in Ref. 1. Instead he assumes eqs. (1)-(3).

   - E.g. the force  $\hat{F}^j$ in eq. (1) could in principle contain dissipative forces incompatible with a Hamiltonian formulation.
   - Also note that the commutator $[\dot{\hat{x}}^j,\dot{\hat{x}}^k]$ is not necessarily $0$, so we cannot directly apply the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem) on eqs. (2)-(3).

References:

1. F.J. Dyson, *Feynman’s proof of the Maxwell equations,* [Am. J. Phys. 58 (1990) 209](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.16188).